# Batch File Perform Task After?

Tags: batch-file

I need a batch file to perform a certain operation at a certain time.

I tried searching but, I couldn't find something similar to my question (They are mostly based on the Task Scheduler)

Now i know how to save the date and time into a text file and read from the data using fart.exe but, I would like to perform the same task every time after 12 hours interval (Just an example).

Example. At start up I performed a task and saved the date and time into a text file (I can read from it also). Now i just need to know that how to perform the same task after 12 hours or less. How can i accomplish that?

Comment: Why can't you use the Task Scheduler?

Comment: Try [here](http://serverfault.com/questions/9038/run-a-bat-file-in-a-scheduled-task-without-a-window)

Comment: Because it doesn't have to be Task Scheduler dependent and I want to test it with pure batch script.

@user4317867 - Thank you but, something without Task Scheduler would be much better approach.